# How do I prevent decimal rounding in the middle of an operation?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm trying to perform an operation that will find number of pizza slice (homework assignment) from the user's input of diameter, but my problem is that c++ keeps rounding down in the middle of the operation. Here's the code

```
//Calculates the number of slices that can be obtained using the diameter from the user's input
    sliceNumber = (pi *(pow((pizzaDiameter/ 2.0 ) , 2.0 ))) / sliceArea;

//Outputs the number of slices that can be cut, accurate to 1 decimal point using the command "setprecision"
    cout << "The number of slices your pizza can be divided into is ";
    cout << setprecision(2) << sliceNumber << endl;
```

The end result should be rounded to one decimal place, that is correct since it was forced with setprecision. But when I did the problem on my own with a calculator the result is a little different. For example I would input the diameter as 10 in the program and it will output 5.4, even though on a real calculator it's 5.6. (the # of slices is found by finding the area of the pizza then dividing it by 14.125, which is declared with `sliceArea`)

`pi` is declared as a constant integer of 3.14 and both `sliceNumber` and `sliceDiameter` are declared as doubles. `sliceArea` is declared as an int of 14.125.

Comment: *pi is declared as a constant integer of 3.14*  What !  I infer from your question that you are a beginner.  If necessary skip forward in your tutorial to the pages where the differences between integers and floating-point numbers are explained.  Or skip back if you read that page rather too quickly.

Comment: Posting a question about "why does this not give the expected result" in a strongly-typed language (like C++), but not including the type declaration in the example code, means the question is unclear. The exact type of each variable is a crucial part of any C++ code example. Stating their type in the prose is not enough, because we cannot be sure that you mean what you say, and really say what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

If `sliceArea` is an `int`, then the value is 14, not 14.125. Similarly, if `pi` is an `int`, the value is 3, not 3.14. Not coincidentally, `(3 * pow(10 / 2.0, 2.0)) / 14` comes to `5.357...` which would round to `5.4` with two digits of precision. You need to declare these values to be `double` (or `float`) or your compiler will just truncate the fractional value to get an `int`.

Comment: Note: I'd hope most compilers would warn you about defining `const int` as equal to a `double` literal; you might want to turn up the warning level on your compiler, or pay attention to the warnings it's giving you.